# Reading JSON objects from javascript file using JINT

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, json, jint

I've been supplied with a javascript file containing two JSON objects such as this.

```
var languages = {"Languages":["English","Cymraeg","Deutsch"]};
var labels = [{"$JOB":["Job","Orchwyl","Auftrag",]},{"$JOB_NO":["Job Number","Rhiforchwyl","Auftragsnummer"]}];
```

I need to serialise the two JSON objects into something I can manipulate within .NET. I'm using JINT to get the two values from the file like this.

```
Engine js = new Engine();
js.Execute(fileContents);
languages = js.GetValue("languages");
labels = js.GetValue("labels");
```

But I can't do anything with the two values now. I can't parse the JSON, the values just come out as a strange object array where I can't actually determine the values.

Any suggestions on how I can get access to the JSON objects?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no JSON here.
This is javascript code, that creates javascript objects when it's evaluated.

Now, you can convert that javascript object into a JSON string.
The simplest way I found, was to have JINT do it for me, but I'm no expert in Jint, there might be better ways.

```cs
// Run javascript, inside the interpreter, to create JSON strings
js.Execute("languages = JSON.stringify(languages)");
js.Execute("labels = JSON.stringify(labels)");
// Extract the strings from the JS environment, into your c# code as strings
// Now, you can deserialize them as normal JSON
var languagesJsonString = js.GetValue("languages").AsString();
var labelsJsonString = js.GetValue("labels").AsString();
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this though and I get an exception as the return from GetValue is not a string.

Comment: I'm being a spanner, I hadn't executed the JSON.Stringify aspects... works a treat now, thanks.